# Reverse certificate DN

Tags: perl, scep, openxpki

could someone please assist me with reversing the DN of a certificate. (I have never used `perl` before so I don't know what the best practices are).

I have the following string:

```
$issuer = "DC=ORG,DC=OpenXPKI,OU=Test CA,CN=CA ONE";
```

And I would need this:

```
$issuer = "CN=CA ONE,OU=Test CA,DC=OpenXPKI,DC=ORG";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
$issuer = join ",", reverse split (/,/, $issuer);
```

split your string on commas, reverse the ordering, and then join them back together (with commas)

Comment: indeed the best method yes,